# Not finding the library files directed to in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to compile this tool. Below is the beginning of its Makefile:

```
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -Wall -O2 -D TRACES
DFLAGS  = -g -Wall -o0
CPPFLAGS= $(INCLUDES:%=-I %)
LDFLAGS = $(LIBRARIES:%=-L %)
LDLIBS  = $(USED_TOOLS:%=-l%)

MY_FILES = 
INCLUDE_DIR     = ~/include

TOOLBOX_INC     = $(INCLUDE_DIR)/tools
TOOLBOX_LIB     = $(TOOLBOX_INC)
USED_TOOLS      = std_io stringutils 
INCLUDES    = $(TOOLBOX_INC)
LIBRARIES   = $(TOOLBOX_LIB)
```

I also have ~/include/tools which after compiling includes std_io.o, libstd_io.a, stringutils.o and libstringutils.a

I am getting the following error:

```
gcc -L ~/include/tools rank.o counterexample.o -lstd_io -lstringutils -o rank
ld: library not found for -lstd_io
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [rank] Error 1
```

I am not sure if things are not included correctly, and why it is not finding the library files.

**Edit:** turns out I accidentally left a space between the -L and -I options. Also, the paths had to be expanded I guess. It's working now, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your `~` is getting expanded to your home directory? Try using the full path for `INCLUDE_DIR`.

Comment: Does it work from the command line?

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions on `libstd_io.a`?

Comment: If it's working now, put an answer in and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 17):

The problem is the use of the tilde to mean "Home directory". A shell will do tilde expansion only if the tilde is the first nonquoted character in a word. Makefiles never do tilde expansion. Thus, in

```
gcc -L~/include ...
```

the shell **does not** perform tilde expansion and gcc will look for a directory named "~/include" in the current directory. But in

```
gcc -L ~/include ...
```

the shell **does** perform tilde expansion and gcc sees

```
gcc -L /usr/username/include ...
```

instead, which works as expected. The right thing to do is to never use tilde expansion for the home directory, but simply use $HOME appropriately in the Makefile, e.g.

```
INCLUDE_DIR     = $$HOME/include
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Some how it was hard for me to find out this bit about tilde expansion.