# ld cannot link to a library, that 100% there

Tags: c++, ld

Try to link against libxxx which is here:

```
❯ ls -al ~/.local/lib/
total 56292
drwxr-xr-x  2 muse user     4096 Jun 23 23:57 .
drwx------ 11 muse user     4096 Jun 23 23:02 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 muse user       40 Jun 23 23:51 libxxx.so -> /home/muse/.local/lib/libxxx.so.0.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 muse user 57622768 Jun 23 23:02 libxxx.so.0.0.1
```

if I try to open in via shortname (xxx), getting an error:

```
❯ ld -L~/.local/lib/ -lxxx --verbose | grep -i '~/.local/lib//libxxx.so'
ld: cannot find -lxxx
attempt to open ~/.local/lib//libxxx.so failed
```

But I can directly access it via full path:

```
❯ ld ~/.local/lib//libxxx.so
ld: warning: libprotobuf.so.23.1.0, needed by /home/muse/.local/lib//libxxx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
....
```

Comment: [Some good reading with links to more good reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42018118/4581301)

Comment: It is my belief that you _can_ link directly against a `.so` file, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/726390/5743288  Is that `~` being expanded properly?  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7197011/5743288

Comment: @user4581301  why do you think it will look for libxxx.a?
if you do -lstdc it will look for so, for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between $HOME and '~' (tilde)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587343/difference-between-home-and-tilde/11587409#11587409)

Comment: @user4581301, no, you're wrong, you can (and very often do) link directly to a shared library, it's only on Windows where you need a static loader library for shared libraries

Answer (score 1):

Shells (typically) only interpret `~` as meaning your home directory *at the beginning of words*. In `ld ~/.local/lib/libxxx.so`, `~` appears at the beginning of the word, so the shell replaces `~` with `/home/muse` and the `ld` program is run with the arguments: `ld` (argument 0) and `/home/muse/.local/lib/libxxx.so` (argument 1). `ld` attempts to open the file and succeeds.

But when you type `ld -L~/.local/lib/ -lxxx`, the `~` is *not* at the beginning of a word. The shell doesn't process the argument specially and the `ld` program is run with arguments `ld`, `-L~/.local/lib/`, and `-lxxx`. Programs other than shells generally do not (and should not) interpret `~` as meaning the home directory; they just interpret it as a normal file name. So the command `ld -L~/.local/lib/ -lxxx` looks for `libxxx.so` in the directory `./~/.local/lib/`, a subdirectory of the current directory which probably doesn't exist.

The general solution is to use the `$HOME` variable instead of the `~` shorthand, to tell the shell that you really do intend to expand something in the middle of a word.

```bash
ld "-L$HOME/.local/lib/" -lxxx
```

Your `ld` *might* be sufficiently modern to allow `-L` and the path to appear as separate arguments, in which case

```bash
ld -L ~/.local/lib -lxxx       # or
ld -L "$HOME/.local/lib" -lxxx
```

would also work.